# Hiding HTML Elements with no Id and Class Name in a WebView

Tags: android

I have gone through multiple question on stack overflow but could not find working answer. I need to hide html elements with no id and class name in webview android.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's probably impossible to do it in Java so you need to do it in Javascript. Second problem is that I don't think there is a simple or good enough way to do that. If you own the HTML page try to add id or class to elements you want to hide.

When you do that you can run it like this:

```
String classToHide = "some-class";
String jsCode = "for (let el of document.querySelectorAll('." + classToHide + "')) el.style.visibility = 'hidden';";
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    webView.evaluateJavascript(jsCode, null);
} else {
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + jsCode);
}
```

Note that you need javacsript enabled like this:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```